# Where can I find a list of the GDK_comma, GDK_dollar, ... constants?

Tags: c, gtk, gdk

A C project contains a couple of lines including `GDK_comma`, `GDK_dollar`, `GDK_o`, etc. Where can I find a list of these constants?

Specifically, I'm looking for the constant for `ö` (`&ouml;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the headers for GDK. On my system it is:

```
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkkeysyms-compat.h
```

Comment: Thanks! I found `GDK_odiaeresis 0x0f6` in that file.

Comment: No problem. Just in case you need to find other things like that, all I did was `grep 'GDK_comma'/usr/include/* -R` which does a recursive search in all the header files for the known information.